# How can I get more detailed information about asana tasks?

Tags: api, asana

I saw an example of "QUERYING FOR TASKS", but it only returns the id and name of the tasks, I would like to get more information about tasks (for example created_at, completed, due_on, followers, etc) by querying them with API.

Answer (score 3):

(I work for Asana)

See the section on input/output options in the docs: https://asana.com/developers/documentation/getting-started/input-output-options

By default, objects that are subobjects or that are returned from queries are output in "compact" form, which is usually just ID and name. If you want more detail for those objects, you can specify specific fields to include in the output using the `opt_fields` parameter. You can get *all* available fields on an object by "expanding" them with `opt_expand`. So if you are querying for tasks and want full records instead of compact ones, use `opt_expand=.`

Comment: Would it be possible to include previous version/history of tasks in the query?
Specifically, I am interested in all tasks within a section, with all task history information included.